# What does 专门用来找工作 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 来自西北民族大学的小郑也选择到北京找工作，她问记者展示了她的“求职基金”，“我在研二时获得了国家奖学金，除去学费还剩1万多元，这些钱我存在了一张卡里，**专门用来找工作**。

I understand the meaning before the bold part, which tells a student stocked money for job searching. But what does the bold part mean and how can I breat down the components grammatically? 专门 likely means the speciality of jobs, but then the sentence doesn't make sense for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [专门](http://www.zdic.net/c/3/16/33464.htm) - specially
- 用 - use ("used" here)
- 来 - for
- 找工作 - job searching/seeking

So the whole sentence means "(the stocked money) is used for job searching specially".

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I thought 专门 refers to the speciality of jobs, which made me confused. Thanks.

Comment: @Blaszard put that in your question - so we know what you're struggling with - otherwise it seems a bit like a straightforward translation request.

Comment: @user3306356 Yup sorry for that... I rushed too much.

Comment: @Blaszard it's cool, just edit it real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the word "专门" into **exclusively** might be more close to the original means in this scenario .